# Creating file loop

Tags: python, file, while-loop, user-input

How can I ask the user for a file name and if it already exists, ask the user if they want to overwrite it or not, and obey their request. If the file does not exist, a new file (with the selected name) should be created.
From some research on both the Python website and Stack Overflow, I've come up with this code

```
try:
    with open(input("Please enter a suitable file name")) as file:
        print("This filename already exists")

except IOError:
    my_file = open("output.txt", "r+")
```

But this will not run in Python, and doesn't do everything I want it to do.

Comment: Did you forget a `)` right before `as file`?

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Are you concerned with race conditions of checking for file existence?

Comment: I added the ) by the as file so now it will run, but when asking for a file name it will automatically say it has been used before, even if it hasn't

Comment: Race conditions : there's lots of different things (overwriting files, creating files, all in a while loop, checking for previous file existence etc) so I'm just a bit stuck ! Although there are solutions to most of those issues, I'm struggling to apply and combine them for my own use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative soltution would be (however the user would need to provide a full path):

```
import os

def func():
    if os.path.exists(input("Enter name: ")):
        if input("File already exists. Overwrite it? (y/n) ")[0] == 'y':
            my_file = open("filename.txt", 'w+')
        else:
            func()

    else:
    my_file = open("filename.txt", 'w+')
```

Don't forget to close the file object when it's not needed anymore with `my_file.close()`.

Comment: Hi I tried your solution in a separate python file just on its own and the following error came up Enter nametesting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 6, in <module>
    my_file = open("filename.txt", 'r+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.txt'

Comment: I changed that, and now this error appears my_file = open("filename.txt", 'r+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.txt'

Comment: The error message still has `'r+'` in it. Did you save the script before running it?

Comment: Isn't `os.path.isfile` a better choice since OP wants to check for regular files?

Comment: @sxnwlfkk I thought I had edited, but clearly hadn't. Done it again and it seems to work, but when I enter the same name, the program just accepts it

Comment: @SilentMonk I changed it to os.path.isfile - will this make any difference when coding? Or does it just mean I am using the more 'correct' techniques?

Comment: @SilentMonk @Ollie I'm not sure, since it could cause trouble in Linux. If the user wants a filename, and it doesn't exists as a file, but as a dir, `os.path.isfile` could lead to creating a file with a dir's name (which you can't, or shouldn't, or I don't know).

Comment: @sxnwlfkk I was actually thinking the other way round. If the input provided by the user matches an existing directory by chance, then it wouldn't provide the expected results. But your argument too holds good. I think the OP should take a decision on this based on the possible inputs.

Comment: I used your current code which pretty much works but I'd like it so that, if the user does not want to overwrite the file with the same name, the code loops back and the user is asked for another file name

Comment: I used your current code again to double check(using the same file name multiple times), and now sometimes it will come up saying to overwrite the file, and sometimes it doesn't and I have no idea why. Weirdly enough 'dog' always triggers it.

Comment: @Ollie Added recursion. Don't know, why it behaves that way. With my setup (python3 on Ubuntu 16.04) it works consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.exists` to check if a file already exists are not.

```
if os.path.exists(file path):
    q = input("Do you want to overwrite the existing file? ")
    if q == (your accepted answer):
       #stuff
else:
    #stuff
```

You could do this with a try / except if you want to abide by the whole "easier to ask for forgiveness" motto, but I think this is cleaner.

Comment: What do you put in the (file path) ?

Comment: Isn't `os.path.isfile` a better choice since OP wants to check for regular files?

Comment: You could do this as one option `file_path= input("Specify the file path")`

Comment: Why do they need to specify the file path?

Comment: Why do you mean why do they need to specify a file path? Your entire question centers around doing this and then checking for existence etc....